# Search box of Google Maps not working in localhost

Tags: javascript

When I try to tap location in my search box, I get this message with an exclamation mark:

[image: grey message box with exclamation mark and message “Petit problème... Une erreur s'est produite”]

This is my code:

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<input id="searchTextField" type="text" size="50">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
        var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Comment: Have you acquired an API key in the [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/maps_backend/overview)? It's possible that you need to add a key to your query string.

Comment: Also, which of the two Maps related lines of code produces the error?

Comment: When I add ?key=' _____'  i get this error "Google Maps API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError"

Comment: That means you need to whitelist your domain (localhost in this case) on the [Credentials screen of the Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials). Google requires this in order to prevent misuse of your API key, since it's contained in the HTML document and everybody can read it.

Comment: I add my domaine (localhost) but it gives the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google checks the referer based on the address that the request came from. That means, you have to have an actual webserver running and access your document via, say, `http://localhost/maps.html`.

When you directly open your html file from the disk, your address will be something like `file:///C:/www/maps.html`. This is obviously not in the referer list in the Cloud Console, hence the `RefererNotAllowedMapError`.